# Any tips on what to do about my rabbit that just died?

Tags: death, senior-pet

My daughter's pet rabbit has just died. I have a garden but burying her might be too hard as there are thick tree roots in that area. What other options are there?

The rabbit died of old age; she made it to 10 years, so she lived a long life, well loved and spoiled.

Answer (score 3):

A dead body should be buried quite deep to avoid attracting scavengers and insects. Depending on your local rules it may be prohibited to bury dead pets on your property.

If you insist on giving your pet a (semi-)permanent resting place, there might be pet graveyards in your local area. This is usually tied to some costs.

There might also be pet cremation services in your area (I have no experiences with them, but several users pointed them out in the comments). Usually you have the option to receive your pet's ashes and either keep them or scatter them in a way you see fit. Otherwise the service provider will scatter the remains in a proper way.

I advice against burying her in the woods at night or something like that. The police might ask you some very uncomfortable questions if someone sees you and draws the wrong conclusion.

Usually vet clinics do accept the bodies of pets and dispose of them in a sanitary way. Where I live all vet clinics are required to accept dead pets, but that certainly depends on your local rules.

Comment: And depending on locale, there might be cremation services for pets available, where you get the ashes back. You can then either keep them or scatter them as you see fit.

Comment: When my dog passed on - we checked with our vet on properly handling his remains. They recommended a local pet cremation service, and least locally, you had the option of taking back the cremains, or having the ashes scattered at sea. Your options may vary locally - and your vet would know what's best